# Receiving 302 as success response instead of failure

Tags: http-status-code-302

I am receiving 302 response for SOAP service from tibco middleware, but instead of getting errored out it is getting completed successfully. Is 302 a success response?

Comment: TIBCO ActiveMatrix BusinessWorks, which I assume you mean with TIBCO Middleware, has the option to override HTTP status codes so while Remy's answer below is correct, you might want to also check with the team that built the service to see what their understanding of the status code is.

Answer (score 0):

[Response code 302](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) is a redirect to a different url. Repeat the request using the new url instead.